# how do I send (put) multiple files using nodejs ssh2-sftp-client?

Tags: node.js

If I try more then 10 files I got the warning, but the other files are not uploaded, I cannot upload more than 10 files. What am I doing wrong?

> { node:17472) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter
>   memory leak detected. 11 ready listeners added. Use
>   emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit (node:17472)
>   MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to
>   increase limit (node:17472) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible
>   EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use
>   emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit }

```
 let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
    let sftp = new Client();
    var promises = [];
    for(var i=0; i < 12; i++) {
        promises.push(sendFile(sftp, req.body, results.romlist[i].filename));
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        sftp.end();
        res.send('{"message":"OK"}');
    });
      const sendFile = (sftp, config, filename) => {
console.log(filename);
return sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
    return sftp.put(filename, "/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/atari2600/" + filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, 'catch error');
});};
```

Comment: i would probably create a tar stream. creating new connections for each file is overhead

Comment: that would be a nice idea, but I need the individual files in the destionation machine, so if I zip after sending it I would need to perform an ssh and unzip it in the target machine

Comment: you are aware you can use ssh to run a tar extraction on the remote machine based on stdin? still you should disable stderr from the sending machine or else you'll end up with garbage within the tar stream.

Comment: this should do the magic (kind of untested but obvious): `$ tar cf - * 2> /dev/null | ssh foo@bar "(cd /some/folder; tar xf -)"`

Comment: ps: you could also use rsync or something more advanced like syncthing since they support two way sync (nice for save games)

Answer (score 2):

Below code using es6-promise-pool as an example and it is working for me:

First need to install es6-promise-pool:

```
npm install es6-promise-pool --save
```

Code:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let PromisePool = require('es6-promise-pool');

var files = [ (list of files to transfer) ]; // results.romlist[i].filename
var config = { (sftp config) };

const sendFile = (config, filename) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let sftp = new Client();
    console.log(filename);
    sftp.on('keyboard-interactive', (name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish) => { finish([config.password]); });
    sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
        return sftp.put("(local path)" + filename, "/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/atari2600/" + filename);
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('finish '+filename);
        sftp.end();
        resolve(filename);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, 'catch error');
    });
  });
};

var count = 0;
var sendFileProducer = function () {
    console.log("count="+count);
    if (count < 100) {
        count++;
        return(sendFile(config, files[count]));     
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

// The number of promises to process simultaneously.
var concurrency = 10;

// Create a pool.
var pool = new PromisePool(sendFileProducer, concurrency)

pool.start().then(function () {
    console.log({"message":"OK"}); // res.send('{"message":"OK"}');
});
```

The code does not optimized for network traffic since it start a SFTP for each file. However, it is still very effective as you can control the concurrency that suit for different situations.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the connection open? I have tried it but did not work. I have over 500 files to transfer and this way I will be opening 500 connections

Comment: If you have 500 files to process using a fixed number of workers you may try to develop using pool concept. Some reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-pool

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client/issues/73

```
const putFiles = (sftpConfig, fileList) => {
  const sftp = new sftpClient()
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    sftp
    .connect(sftpConfig)
    .then(() => {
      return Promise.all(fileList.map(args => {
        return sftp.put.apply(sftp, args)
      }))
    })
    .then(() => sftp.end())
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject)
  });
}
```

Comment: this approach will detect memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

The npm package "**sftp-upload**" worked for me to upload more than 10 files in a directory to a remote server.
You can refer this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/sftp-upload

Please find the below example code in nodejs, which I have tested and it will work . Please substitute your required data for the fields :

- **username**: sftp server's username.
- **path**: Path to a directory(in the local system) containing the files that is going to be uploaded to the server.
- **remoteDir**:Path in the remote directory where files are going to be uploaded.

```js
var SftpUpload = require('sftp-upload');
var fs = require('fs');
         
       sftp2 = new SftpUpload({
            host:'remote ip address',
            username:'username',
            password:'****',
            path: '/user/Desktop/test1',
            remoteDir: '/user/Desktop/test1',
            excludedFolders: ['**/.git', 'node_modules'],
            exclude: ['.gitignore', '.vscode/tasks.json'],
            dryRun: false
        });
     
        sftp2.on('error', function(err) {
            throw err;
        })
        .on('uploading', function(progress) {
            console.log('Uploading', progress.file);
            console.log(progress.percent+'% completed');
        })
        .on('completed', function() {
            console.log('Upload Completed');
        })
        .upload();
```

*This code will copy all the files present in the "test1" directory in the local system to the "test1" directory in the remote server. If the "test1" directory is not present in the remote server, it will be automatically created and the files will be copied.*

*If there is subfolder inside the "test1" directory ,then that subfolder and it's contents will also be copied to the remote machine.*