# upload multiple files to sftp server using Rxjs

Tags: rxjs, sftp, es6-promise

Good Day! I would like to implement a convenient method for uploading a multiple files to an sftp-server with methods of calling back each ofuploaded files to server.

I have already tried to implement some code that works, but I saw that there is a memory leak that does not allow to successfully close the connection to the sftp server server after all download.

it is absolutely not critical to constantly open the connection and close it for me.

I tweaked the code a little bit from here:  [how do I send (put) multiple files using nodejs ssh2-sftp-client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521222/how-do-i-send-put-multiple-files-using-nodejs-ssh2-sftp-client?answertab=active#tab-top)

**code:**

```
function sftpPutFiles(config, files, pathToDir, callbackStep, callbackFinish, callbackError) {
    let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
    let PromisePool = require('es6-promise-pool');

    const sendFile = (config, pathFrom, pathTo) => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let sftp = new Client();
            console.log(pathFrom, pathTo);
            sftp.on('keyboard-interactive', (name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish) => { finish([config.password]); });
            sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
                return sftp.put(pathFrom, pathTo);
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('finish '+pathTo);
                callbackStep(pathTo);
                sftp.end();
                resolve(pathTo);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err, 'catch error');
                callbackError(err);
            });
        });
    };


    // Create a pool.
    let indexFile = 0;
    let pool = new PromisePool(() => {
        while (indexFile < files.length) {
            let file = files[indexFile];
            indexFile++;
            return sendFile(config, file.path, `${pathToDir}/${file.name}`);
        }
        return null;
    }, 10);

    pool.start().then(function () {
        console.log({"message":"OK"}); // res.send('{"message":"OK"}');
        callbackFinish();
    });
}
```

**using**

```
input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sftpPutFiles(
        {host: '192.168.2.201', username: 'crestron', password: 'ehAdmin'},
        this.files,
        `./Program01/test/`,
        pathTo => {
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            let bodyTable = document.querySelector('.body');
            tr.innerHTML = `<td>${bodyTable.children.length+1}</td><td>${pathTo}</td><td>OK</td>`;
            bodyTable.appendChild(tr);
        }, () => {
            alert('Всё файлы загружены');
        },
        err => {
            alert('Ошибка: '+err);
        }
    );
});
```

[image]

If there is an error uploading the file to the `sftp` server, the connection does not close and I cannot reconnect when I open the custom console. I would like to translate the code to **Rxjs** to better support and I think I can solve the problem of closing the connection and responsiveness of the application.

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure your using the latest version of ssh2-sftp-client - there has been a fair amount of updates recently, including fixes to handle errors more consistently and ensure connections are closed correctly. (v4.1.0).
2. You are using sftp.on('keyboard-interaction', ...). There is nothing which emits events of this type in the module, so this listener will not fire.
3. If you just want to upload files, use the fastPut() method. It is much faster. Make sure the destination path includes the remote file name and not just the remote directory.
4. Have a look at Promise.all(). You could use this instead of the promise-pool and I think it would be a lot cleaner. Something like (untested)

```
    let localPath = '/path/to/src-dir';
    let remotePath = '/path/to/dst-dir';
    let files = ['file1.txt', file2.txt','file3.txt'];

    let client = new Client();
    client.connect(config)
    .then(() => {
      let promises = [];
      files.forEach(f => {
        let from = path.join(localPath, f);
        let to = path.join(remotePath, f);
        promise.push(client.fastPut(from, to));
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    }).then(res => { // res is array of resoved promise results
       client.end();
    }).catch(err => {
       // deal with error
    });
```